# Sistematicamente recibo un -1 en mis respuestas apenas las publico

Tags: soporte, votos-negativos

hace mucho que soy un miembro silencioso de esta comunidad y hace una semana o dos empece a contestar algunas preguntas para poder aportar ya que aprendi mucho gracias a esta pagina. Pero algo extraño me esta pasando, cada vez que publico una respuesta, en menos de 5 minutos siempre recibo -1 en  mi respuesta.

Al principio pense que mis respuestan podrian estar mal, que simplemente alguien paso por ahi y no le gusto lo que puse. Pero la conducta se repite de forma sistematica y demasiado rapido, tampoco no suelo recibo comentarios negativos al respecto, es más algunas son bien aceptadas.

Jaja espero no estar siendo paranoico, pero me gustaria que algun moderador revisara el caso, si en verdad mis preguntas tienen algo que pueda mejorar para que la gente no me tire tomates antes de que le de enter al teclado me gustaria saberlo tambien.

Por ultimo me gustaria aclarar que, si ven el historial de mis respuestas, no todas tienen -1 porque usualmente alguien me da algun que otro puntito y quedan en 0 o +1 o algo asi, pero me preocupa empezar siempre abajo.

Desde ya muchas gracias.

Answer (score 7):

Revisando un poco tus respuestas, veo que probablemente el problema es que repondes a preguntas que no se ajustan mucho a los estándares de calidad que se piden en el sitio, y algunas de tus respuestas podrían considerarse mas comentarios que respuestas.

Por ejemplo, [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/199286/15301) está en proceso de cierre con 4 votos por no estar claro lo que se pregunta.

Hay una "batalla" por aqui entre los que opinan que las respuestas a malas preguntas deben puntuarse negativamente aunque no sean incorrectas, y los que opinan lo contrario. Es posible que los votos negativos de los que hablas provengan del primer grupo.

De todas maneras...veo que solo has recibido 4 negativos en 19 respuestas (si no he contado mal). No me parece que sea algo para preocuparse, ni que sea algo "sistemático" ni mucho menos.

Por último, yo siempre recomiendo no buscar muchas explicaciones a los votos negativos ni tomárselos como algo personal. Los usuarios del sitio votan (poco para mi gusto pero votan) y cada uno tiene sus razones personales para votar de una u otra manera. Eso se respeta y por eso los votos son privados y nadie puede ver quien voto que. Simplemente sigue aportando y verás como tu reputación sube :)

Comment: Muchas gracias, la verdad no tenia idea que existieran esa clase de internas. No me preocupare entonces.

Comment: @ErickSilva bueno, tal vez "batalla" haya sido excesivo. Son mas bien corrientes de opinión, en las que hay usuarios que consideran que hay que votar negativo a las respuestas a preguntas que no tienen la calidad mínima exigible, y otros que consideran que hay que juzgar la respuesta aisladamente y votarla positivamente si es buena. Los votos al final son algo subjetivo, y no hay nada que se pueda o vaya a hacer para cambiarlo.

Comment: Sobre esa 'batalla' quizá debieran revisar la medalla Reversión: " Proporcionar una respuesta con una puntuación de +20 a una pregunta con una puntuación de -5" (https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/57/reversal) No parece que el sitio fomente votar negativo a repsuestas a mala preguntas.